# Function to send XML via cURL

Tags: php, curl

Here's my function which should send XML to the server specified in the config, and then convert the response (which is XML) to an array..

```
public function xmlResponse($data) {
    // sends the request to Atheme's XMLRPC interface via cURL
    $request = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $this->atheme_host);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close', 'Content-Type: text/xml'));
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);

    // converts recieved XML into a PHP array and returns
    return json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($response)), 1);
}
```

However, this returns False when I do a var_dump. I'm not sure what the problem is and have been diagnosing it for a while now. Would be grateful if someone could point out the problem and a solution. It's something wrong with cURL I believe.

Thanks!

Comment: Show a `var_dump` of `$data`, it may not be a proper post string.

Comment: `
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall><methodName>atheme.login</methodName><params><param><value><string>Sample Username</string></value></param><param><value><string>password123</string></value></param><param><value><string>123.456.78.94</string></value></param></params></methodCall>`

This is the XML being sent.

Comment: Yes, you need to [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) that data when you pass it as the value for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: So `curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($data));` would work?

Comment: You should have more luck doing that yes, if you pass a string to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, it must be urlencoded.

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't work.

Comment: Try calling [curl_getinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) at the end and see if there is any reason in there why it is failing.

Comment: `Array ( [url] => [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) )`

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any info.  Did you pass `$request` to curl_getinfo() prior to closing the handle?

Comment: Yep, I passed $request on before closing the handle. It seems that it isn't requesting anything... Hmm...

Comment: Yea, you may want to confirm the URL is valid, I copied your code before and it worked fine for me by changing only the URL.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7321/discussion-between-fike-and-drew010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not being familiar with Atheme or its API, I'm not sure if this will help or not, but some APIs that accept XML work like this:

```
$header = "Connection: close\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $data;

$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $this->atheme_host);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);
$response = curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);
```